# Epsilon Delta proof of a limit of a multivariate function

Tags: calculus, limits

Please help me solve this problem. Show that $\lim_{\substack{x \to 0 \\y \to 1}} \left(ye^x\right) =1$ using epsilon delta method.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE.  Please state your problem clearly. Also show your efforts in solving it.

Comment: See this MathJax tutorial for edit your posts http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-referencecan or explore a  formula when you made click with the right bottom of your mouse over a formula selecting *Show Math As*, and after *Text Commands*, and using dollars symbols as is explained in Meta (previous link). Is usual to encourage users to provide their attempts and context. Welcome.

Answer (score 3):

Let $\epsilon > 0$.  We want to find some $\delta$ so that $|(x,y) - (0,1)| < \delta$ implies $|ye^{x} - 1e^{0}| < \epsilon$.

But $$\begin{split} |ye^{x} - 1e^{0}| &= |ye^{x} - ye^{0} + ye^{0} - 1e^{0}|\\ &\leq |ye^{x} - ye^{0}| + |ye^{0} - 1e^{0}|  \\ &= |y||e^{x} - e^{0}| + |y - 1| \end{split}$$

Now, since all norms on $\Bbb R^{2}$ are equivalent, we can choose the norm that makes this proof easier.  I will choose the norm $|(x,y) - (x', y')| = \max\{|x-x'|, |y - y'|\}$.

Since $e^{x}$ is continuous at $0$, we can find $\delta' > 0$ such that $|x- 0| < \delta'$ implies $|e^{x} - e^{0}| < \frac{\epsilon}{2M}$, where $M = \max \{ |1 - \epsilon|, |1 + \epsilon| \}$ (see the work below to see where $M$ came from).

Let $\delta = \min\{\delta', \frac{\epsilon}{2}\}$.  Then if $|(x,y) - (0,1)| < \delta'$, we have $|x - 0| < \delta$ and $|y - 1| < \delta$.  In particular, $|y - 1| < \frac{\epsilon}{2} < \epsilon$, so that $- \epsilon < y -1 < \epsilon$, i.e., $-\epsilon + 1 < y < \epsilon + 1$, so that $|y| \leq M$ with $M$ defined as above.

Thus, if $|(x,y) - (0,1)| < \delta$, then $$|ye^{x} - 1e^{0}| \leq |y||e^{x} - e^{0}| + |y - 1| \leq M\left (\frac{\epsilon}{2M} \right) + \frac{\epsilon}{2} = \epsilon$$

Comment: THANX A LOT!! THIS WAS EXACTLY WHAT I WANTED! :)